# Ngxs action is not automaticly subscribed to, if run as a unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ngxs

i have an action, which handles a request to the server. While everything is fine when the application is deployed, it stops working if i run unit tests. 
After some time I found out that the action is not being subscribed to, which happens normally.
I'm using the TestBed of Angular. The CreateContact Action is being dispatched and the create method of the service returns an observable which emits a value.

Do any of you have an idea, what the problem could be?

**The Action in question**

```
@Action(CreateContactPageActions.CreateContact)
public createContact(
  ctx: StateContext<ContactStateModel>,
  action: CreateContactPageActions.CreateContact
): Observable<Contact> {
  ctx.patchState({
    error: null
  });

  return this.contactService.create(action.payload)
    .pipe(
      tap(contact => {
        ctx.dispatch(new ContactStateActions.CreateContactSuccess(contact));
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        ctx.dispatch(new ContactStateActions.CreateContactFailed(err));
        return EMPTY;
      }),
    );
}
```

**The configuration of the TestBench**

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports     : [
    TranslateModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientTestingModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide : TranslateLoader,
        useClass: TranslateFakeLoader
      }
    }),
    NgxsModule.forRoot([]),
    NgxsModule.forFeature([ContactState]),
  ],
  declarations: [
    CreateContactPageComponent,
    ContactFormComponent,
    FormFieldErrorsComponent,
    ToFieldValidationErrorMessagesPipe,
  ],
  providers   : [

    {provide: Router, useValue: routerMock},
    {provide: ContactService, useClass: ContactServiceMock},
    Actions,
  ],
}).compileComponents();
```

Comment: Is the ContactState definitely being loaded by NGXS when testing?

Comment: I debuged the action and the ContactState is being loaded and the create-method is being called

Comment: Can you post the code for the service?

Comment: During the test, the service-method just returns a `of(true)` and during a normal run, the real service returns an observable of a http-Post request using the HttpClient of angular